# Limit the number of duplicate rows in SQL query result

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a sql query that returns duplicate rows. I want refine the result so that the duplicate rows are limited to 5. How can I do this ?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data with desired result would helpful with appropriate DBMS tag.

Answer (score 1):

This will work pretty generally, but it assumes your DBMS supports ROW_NUMBER(). You should tag your DBMS, better solutions may be possible ... or this one might not even work.

```
SELECT All,
       of, 
       your,
       columns     
  FROM (SELECT T1.*
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                 ( PARTITION BY All,
                                Of,
                                Your,
                                Columns
                 ) AS rn
          FROM Table1 T1
       ) TMP
 WHERE rn <= 5;
```